# includes php files from subfolder in the root

Tags: php

I am just setting a project up, and I cannot make my header work from a subfolder.

From subfolder/mypage.php I would like to call the resources/includes/header-test.php. It have always worked for me to do that like this:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources/includes/header-test.php'; ?>
```

I cannot solve this, so does anybody have a suggestion how I can do this?

Comment: `<?php include '../resources/includes/header-test.php'; ?>`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. That will not work.

Comment: Your error message infers that `/customers/0/f/c/vouzalis.com/httpd.www` is your document root.  Not `/customers/0/f/c/vouzalis.com/httpd.www/testProject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php include __DIR__.'/../resources/includes/header-test.php'; ?>
```

Comment: That is actually working. Thank a lot for that. Then I just have to figure out what I am gonna do when I have to link to CSS files there is in a subfolder. But I will see. Thank you a lot for that.

Comment: Can you tell me why my code is not working this time? I would really like to know.